# Nested navigation with bottom bar in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I have a RootGraph that contains the next code:

```
@Composable
fun RootNavGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = CommonRoute.Splash.route,
        route = GeneralGraph.ROOT
    ) {
        composable(CommonRoute.Splash.route) { SplashScreen(navController = navController) }
        authNavigation(navController)
        composable(CommonRoute.MainBody.route) {
            MainBody()
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create a login flow, when your session expires one would want to navigate from the bottom graph back to the rootGraph.

```
@Composable
fun MainBody(navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()) {
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            CustomBottomBar(navController = navController)
        }
    ) {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(it)
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            MainNavGraph(navController)
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun MainNavGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = MainGraph.MAIN,
        route = GeneralGraph.MAIN
    ) {
        mainNavigation(navController = navController)
    }
}

fun NavGraphBuilder.mainNavigation(navController: NavHostController) {
    navigation(route = MainGraph.MAIN, startDestination = MainRoute.Home.route) {
        composable(MainRoute.Home.route) {
            HomeScreen(
                navController = navController,
                onUserNotRegistered = {
                    navController.navigate(GeneralGraph.AUTH) {
                        popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id)
                    }
                }
            )
        }
        composable(MainRoute.Post.route) { PostScreen(navController = navController) }
        composable(MainRoute.Profile.route) {
            //val viewModel: ProfileViewModel = hiltViewModel()
            ProfileScreen(navController = navController, onSignOut = { })
        }
    }
}
```

At the start, it loads the Splash screen and goes to the Home Screen to check if a user exists, otherwise I want it to send me to the Auth graph.
Likewise, when I log out from my profile screen that is in the options of my bottom bar, it sends me to the authentication graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first put below code in main activity

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
RootNavigationGraph(navController = navController)
```

create new RootNavigationGraph.kt and put below code

```
@Composable
    fun RootNavigationGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = Screen.Login.route
        ) {
            composable(Screen.Login.route) {
                PhoneLoginScreen(navController = navController)
            }
            composable(Screen.Home.route) {
                BottomNavigationScreen(rootNavController = navController)
            }
        }
    }
```

create new BottomNavigationScreen.kt and put below code

```
@Composable
fun BottomNavigationScreen(rootNavController: NavController) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState(
        drawerState = rememberDrawerState(initialValue = DrawerValue.Closed)
    )

    val activity = LocalContext.current as Activity
    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination
    BackHandler {
        if (currentRoute?.route == BottomNavigationItem.HOME.route){
            activity.finish()
        }
    }

    Scaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        bottomBar = { CustomBottomNavigation(navController = navController) }
    ) {
        Box(modifier = androidx.compose.ui.Modifier.padding(it)) {
            BottomNavigationGraph(
                navController = navController
            )
        }
    }
}
```

create new BottomNavigationGraph.kt and put below code

```
@Composable
fun BottomNavigationGraph(
    navController: NavHostController,
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Constants.BottomNavigationItemRoute.HOME
    ) {
        composable(BottomNavigationItem.HOME.route) {
            HomeScreen()
        }
        composable(BottomNavigationItem.PEOPLE.route) {
            // other composable screen
        }
        composable(BottomNavigationItem.TASKS.route) {
            // other composable screen
        }
    }
}
```

create new CustomBottomNavigation.kt and put below code

```
@Composable
fun CustomBottomNavigation(navController: NavController) {
    val items = mutableListOf(
        BottomNavigationItem.HOME,
        BottomNavigationItem.PEOPLE,
        BottomNavigationItem.TASKS
    )
    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination
    BottomNavigation {
        items.forEach { item ->
            BottomNavigationItem(
                icon = {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = item.icon),
                        contentDescription = item.title
                    )
                },
                label = {
                    Text(
                        text = item.title,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
                        fontSize = 10.sp,
                        style = TextStyle(letterSpacing = 1.8.sp),
                        maxLines = 1
                    )
                },
                selectedContentColor = Secondary,
                unselectedContentColor = White,
                alwaysShowLabel = true,
                selected = currentRoute?.route == item.route,
                onClick = {
                    navController.navigate(item.route) {
                        popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                            inclusive = false
                            saveState = false
                        }
                        launchSingleTop = true
                        restoreState = false
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In `BottomNavigationScreen.kt` you pass `rootNavController` and `topAppBarActions` to `BottomNavigationGraph`, but in `BottomNavigationGraph.kt` we see that it doesn't accept these two parameters. How's that supposed to work?

Comment: Ah sorry, It was used in my app but I forgot to remove it when I pasted it from there. Thanks for reporting this. @Terenfear